# Spring Jaxb2Marshaller External Binding File

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jaxb, unmarshalling

In Spring, I'm declaring my org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller, but I also want to declare an external binding file:

```
<bean id="myMarshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller">
    <property name="contextPath" value="com.path.to.pojos" />
    <property name="jaxbContextProperties">
        <util:map>
            <entry key="eclipselink.oxm.metadata-source">
                <list>
                    <value>com/path/to/schema/binding.xjb</value>
                </list>
            </entry>
        </util:map>
    </property>
    <property name="schema" value="classpath:com/path/to/schema/myService.xsd"/>
</bean>
```

My binding file looks like this:

```
<jaxb:bindings version="1.0" 
    jaxb:version="2.0"
    xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
    xmlns:annox="http://annox.dev.java.net" 
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"
    jaxb:extensionBindingPrefixes="xjc annox">

    <jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="myService.xsd" node="/xs:schema">

        <jaxb:globalBindings>
            <xjc:javaType name="java.util.Date" xmlType="xs:date"
            adapter="com.some.path.to.custom.adapter.DateAdapter" />
        </jaxb:globalBindings>

        <!-- More Declarations -->

        </jaxb:bindings>
    </jaxb:bindings>
```

**This setup works fine with XJC to generate the objects from the schema along with the external binding file. But I can't get the appropriate setup for my Spring configuration.**

I get the following error:

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 9; columnNumber: 77; unexpected     element (uri:"http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb", local:"bindings"). Expected elements are <{http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/xsds/persistence/oxm}xml-schema>,<{http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/xsds/persistence/oxm}xml-schema-type>,<{http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/xsds/persistence/oxm}xml-schema-types>,<{http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/xsds/persistence/oxm}xml-java-type-adapters>,<{http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/xsds/persistence/oxm}xml-registries>,<{http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/xsds/persistence/oxm}xml-enums>,<{http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/xsds/persistence/oxm}java-types>
```

I'm stuck on this, and I really need the binding file to be separate than my schema.  I can't find any example of this setup online, I would love an example on how to properly configure an external binding file with the JaxB2Marshaller.

Please let me know if my question is incomplete or if more information is required.

Thanks,

JP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, bindings file is only used during the compilation time, to derive Java classes from the XML Schema. So it does not make sense to configure it in runtime, on a marshaller. Neither Spring nor JAXB will consider it. All you could have configured with the bindings file is already in your `com.path.to.pojos.*` classes.